# Debian - some applications doesn't launch

Tags: debian, xorg, wayland

I have an issue on my **Debian GNU/Linux 11** (bullseye) (Kernel : 5.10.0-17-amd64) with **KDE**.

Some applications launch (like VSCode, Brave, DBeaver...) but not some others not (like  SQLiteBrowser, Krita..).
They are all in `/usr/bin`. So it seems not a `PATH` issue.
When I check `/var/log/user.log`, I got this kind of issue :

```
Jun 12 15:29:27 debian sqlitebrowser.desktop[14378]: Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
Jun 12 15:29:27 debian sqlitebrowser.desktop[14378]: sqlitebrowser: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/plugins/bearer/libqconnmanbearer.so: undefined symbol: _ZdlPvm, version Qt_5
```

Some applications are not compatible with Wayland ?

Here is the result of `glxinfo -B` :

```
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: Intel (0x8086)
    Device: Mesa Intel(R) UHD Graphics (CML GT2) (0x9b41)
    Version: 20.3.5
    Accelerated: yes
    Video memory: 3072MB
    Unified memory: yes
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 4.6
    Max compat profile version: 4.6
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
OpenGL vendor string: Intel
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) UHD Graphics (CML GT2)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 20.3.5
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 20.3.5
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 20.3.5
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
```

Any idea ?

Comment: This looks like somehow, you installed software that's incompatible to the version of `/usr/lib/plugins/bearer/libqconnmanbearer.so`, or vice versa, you installed a version of `/usr/lib/plugins/bearer/libqconnmanbearer.so` that is incompatible to the software you want to use. Does that sound like something that might have happened lately? Have you manually installed something?

Answer (score 0):

The common denominator of the things that do not work seems to be Qt5; and /usr/lib/plugins/bearer/libqconnmanbearer.so is part of Qt5network5.

This looks like somehow, you installed software that's incompatible to the version of /usr/lib/plugins/bearer/libqconnmanbearer.so, or vice versa, you installed a version of /usr/lib/plugins/bearer/libqconnmanbearer.so that is incompatible to the software you want to use. Does that sound like something that might have happened lately? Have you manually installed something?

- If you think it's likely that something you installed manually overwrote that library, you should remove that manually installed libraries, and reinstall the `libqt5network5` debian package
- If you installed the software that does not work manually and updated, or just copied over executables from a different installation, don't do that; install things only via `apt` (or your debian's graphical package manager), or else you need to re-build your software every time your system updates a library your manually installed software is using.